# cannot run program it says unrecognized token and crashes

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

this is the code its talking about

```
public static final String[] MENU_COLUMNS = {FOOD_NAME,CARBS,SERVING};
private static final String REST = "CREATE TABLE " +MENU_COLUMNS +"(" + FOOD_NAME +" TEXT , "+ CARBS +" TEXT, " + SERVING + " TEXT)";
```

and this is the error code

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider   com.example.diabeticdiner.LocationProvider: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "[Ljava.lang.String;@75ed766(Food_name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, Carbs TEXT, Serving TEXT)" (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE [Ljava.lang.String;@75ed766(Food_name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, Carbs TEXT, Serving TEXT)
```

Comment: Funny name, for a table: `[Ljava.lang.String;@75ed766`... Unfortunately, you are not allowed to use that. Please learn how to get the strings out of your string resources.

Comment: Please share the code where you set `MENU_COLUMNS` value

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> public static final String[] MENU_COLUMNS = {FOOD_NAME,CARBS,SERVING};
> private static final String REST = "CREATE TABLE " +MENU_COLUMNS ...
> ```

`MENU_COLUMNS` does not convert to a string that would be a valid table name. It is a string array, and `toString()` on such produces results like `[Ljava.lang.String;@75ed766`.

Change the code to something like

```
public static final String[] MENU_COLUMNS = {FOOD_NAME,CARBS,SERVING};
private static final String MENU_TABLE = "menu"; // or whatever your table name should be
private static final String REST = "CREATE TABLE " + MENU_TABLE ...
```

Comment: Thank you that worked like a charm